# Insert statement not updating database

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I am experiencing an issue where my PHP code for inserting into a database table is not reflecting changes in the table. I have looked through existing posts and have not found a solution. The previous posts with the same issue usually had glaring issues in the code.

`$stmt->execute()` is returning `True`. I am committing the transaction as well as closing the statement.

This is happening on MariaDB, version 5.5.5.

The table is simple and only contains 2 columns:

`CREATE TABLE gallery (image_type varchar(255), url varchar(800));`

My code is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$type = 'foo';
$url = 'bar';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (image_type, url) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $type, $url);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $conn->commit();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "Success!";
} else {
   echo "Failure!";
}
```

If I connect to the database in command line and run an insert statement it works fine, so I know this is an code issue.

Comment: Do you have MySQLi exceptions switched on?

Comment: Just added `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to my code. Tried again - its not throwing any exceptions.

Comment: What does $stmt->affected_rows() return after execute?

Comment: @GeorgRichter so `$stmt->affected_rows()` didn't exist but I tried  `$conn->affected_rows` and now all of a sudden it is working lol.

Comment: I guess its some issue with the server. If I run `$conn->affected_rows` after an insert statement it works. If I don't it does not.

Comment: How do you know that "Insert statement not updating database"?

Comment: 5.5.5 is not a real version, it's a compatibility prefix. You must have some 10.x server, is it 10.4? There have been several reports about mysteriously missing data after INSERTs, but none has been reproduced so far. If you have any useful information, please add a comment to https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20354 or https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20683 .

Comment: As elenst pointed out, the reason could be one of the two bugs in MariaDB's bug tracking system. `affected_rows()` doesn't do any interaction with server, it just retrieves the value which was returned in the OK packet of last `execute()` call.